# Error: Deployment Update target 8.3 NSMutableArray and addObjectsFromArray - swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

After updating the xcode and my device some functions are not running anymore.
see It:

```
var jsonUnico: NSMutableArray! = jsonResult["lista"] as? NSMutableArray
self.tableList.addObjectsFromArray(jsonUnico)
```

Error: Cannot invoke 'addObjectsFromArray' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableArray!)'

It was working yesterday before upgrading

note: the tablelist is an NSMutableArray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 1.2 no longer implicitly converts between `NSArray` and Swift’s native array type – you need to explicitly cast from one to the other.  Since `addObjectsFromArray` takes a Swift array, that means you need to convert it to `[AnyObject]`.

Normally you’d get a more helpful error message: `error: 'NSMutableArray' is not implicitly convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?`, with a offer to “fix-it”.  But it looks like this isn’t happening because of your use of implicitly-unwrapped optional `NSMutableArray!`.

But… this isn’t such a bad thing, since using implicitly-unwrapped optionals like that when fetching values out of dictionaries is dangerous (if the entry is ever not there, your app will crash).  An alternative is:

```
if let jsonUnico = jsonResult["lista"] as? NSMutableArray {
    let tableList = NSMutableArray()
    // Xcode will recommend adding the "as [AnyObject]"
    tableList.addObjectsFromArray(jsonUnico as [AnyObject])        
}
```

But since you’re already doing an `as` above it, you may as well combine them:

```
if let jsonUnico = jsonResult["lista"] as? [AnyObject] {
    tableList.addObjectsFromArray(jsonUnico)
}
```